# hyperlinked text in word cant be click once made into a pdf

Tags: ms-office, pdf, printing, url

Im using word 2011 to create a doc with hyper linked text using `cmd K` this text is fine when the document is viewed in word as you can click on the text and it opens a browser to view the web page.

But when you pdf the page `flie > print > pdf` the link stays blue but you can no longer click them, any ideas how to resolve this

Comment: I recommend reading these forum posts http://forums.adobe.com/message/4425983

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are opening your documents in Adobe reader (you did not specify) then you need to set the Adobe Reader.

Open Preferences in Adobe Reader and set it to

> Create links from URL's

.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - i didnt specify it because these pdfs tend to get emailed out to 3rd parties, so theres no real way of telling what they are opened with.. but for the above i was opening them preview

Comment: 99.9% of ppl have adobe reader. So setting it up the way I described  will not harm, and when word saves it as pdf it saves it in adobe reader pdf format, that also works for all other pdf readers (like preview) ect.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Steps: create document in Office Mac 2011. File | Export... PDF. Open with Adobe Reader. Create Links from URLs was already checked.   Interestingly, all links in footnotes work, its only links in body text that are disabled.